# Why does Mt gox BTC price discounted with other exchanges?

Tags: bitcoind, mtgox

When ever the BTC prices are crashing, MT Gox prices are discounted. What is the logic behind it?

Comment: mtgox is worried everyone will leave, so they lower the prices. people are already considering bitcoins stored on mtgox as less worth, and ultimately the people decide the price of stuff

Answer (score 3):

MtGox has stopped allowing people to withdraw bitcoins off of the site. What this means is that in an attempt to get money off the site everybody sells their bitcoins to begin wire transfers. When you have a bunch of people selling and no one buying, the price drops.

Mtgox's prices often get discounted because they are isolated from the rest of the bitcoin market, as no one is able to transfer funds from the rest of the market onto MtGox, and vice versa.